# Angular JS uiGmapgoogle-maps add marker after map is loaded

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am able to add markers when initially loaded in AngularJS, but when I try pushing another marker after it does not add it.
Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/76JGKJy9Vu4jtP1ARbJW?p=preview)

```
$scope.addMarkerLocation = function(){
  console.log('adding m');

  var m = 
      {
        id: 3,
        //icon: 'assets/img/blue_marker.png',
        latitude: 25.686384,
        longitude: -80.311644,
        showWindow: false,
        title: 'Jimmyz Kitchen Pinecrest',
        address: '9050 S Dixie Hwy Miami, FL 33156'
      };
  $scope.markers.push(m);
  console.log(m);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create google maps in one instance of `mainCtrl` and then you add another marker in other instance, they don't share the same scope, therefore first instance is unaware of changes, you can either use the button in the same context or use service

```
angular.module('appMaps').factory('markers', function markers () {
    return {
      currentMarkers: []
    }
  })
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kKbEB2ZSHgWQWnCTIvHg?p=preview